# Asus TF700t Ubuntu/Android Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, android, asus, ubuntu-touch

I want to dual boot my transformer infinity.  I like android, but as an IT student it cannot do everything I need homework wise, besides pocket Minecraft sucks.  So I want to have my cake and eat it too.  If anyone knows how I would appreciate a how to.

Comment: It would be just as interesting to 'replace' with Ubuntu (ARM).

Comment: You might want to check out XDA Developers.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the pieces are (still) being developed ..

---

[NVIDIA Releases Tegra 12 Alpha 1 Ubuntu-Based Linux](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTYwNQ)

*Being released by NVIDIA this afternoon is the Tegra 12 Alpha 1 Linux release. This is a Linux software release intended for developers using NVIDIA's Tegra 2 platform.*

*The NVIDIA Tegra Linux 12 Alpha 1 release is based on the Linux 2.6.38 kernel and is derived from Ubuntu. Graphics standards supported by this Tegra-ified Ubuntu release include OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0, EGL 1.3, OpenMAX IL 1.1, and RandR 1.3.*

[NVIDIA >> Linux For Tegra](https://developer.nvidia.com/linux-tegra)

*NVIDIA is pleased to announce Linux for Tegra release 16 is now available. NVIDIA Tegra Linux Driver Package supports development of platforms running:*

- *NVIDIA® Tegra® 3 series T30 (Cardhu developer tablet)*
- *NVIDIA® Tegra® 2 series T20 (Ventana developer tablet)*

---

[XDA Developers >> Eee Pad Transformer Q&A](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1163082)

*[HowTo] Native Ubuntu - Post Install Questions Here not in [DEV] ..*